# bootstrap not working properly please guide me

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

guyz i am having problem in bootstrap it is not refecting result as shown  on official getbootstrap.
like background gradient ,typography and many more not working properly

for example

i simply copy paste the code from bootstrap web

[code from position and input group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LluBm.jpg)

as well as i imported bootstrap.css in styles.css
[bootstrap.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhg9G.jpg)

here what i get
[result look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Vmb.jpg)

i want bootstrap fully functional

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then revise your question to meet the basic requirements of posting here.

Comment: I will say that `col4` isn't a valid Bootstrap class, though.

Comment: Can you share your code as text in code fences (three backticks) instead as image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super proficient with Bootstrap either, but I might have some advice for you for structuring the page based upon the code you showed through images.

Getting started, since you're relatively new to Stack Overflow, I wanted to let you know that you could effectively add the code to your question without having to worry about saving out images and uploading them to a hosting site. Any time you post a question or a response, there's a small navbar at the top of the post box which gives you information on how to set up certain things such as styling, HTML, block quotes and code snippets. If you choose something on this navbar, Stack will give you guidelines on how to implement these sections into your replies to make it easier for others to see and manipulate your code. As an example, three reverse single quotes, `, will give you a code block.

```
Like this
```

It's also always beneficial to post links to any pages you pull code from, or add a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/) link to allow us to see what you're working with!

I hope this helps cut down some of your wait time when asking questions and allows you the opportunity to have more people reach out in response. :)

With the bootstrap conundrum, there's a possibility your file hierarchy might not be accurate when compared to the rest of the documents you've listed that you have access to. By copying code over from other websites, you want to first make sure you've updated links to the file structure of your webpage to ensure that these files load in properly.

For example, you used this code in your styles.css

`@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

It's my understanding that the tilde has a different use in CSS than what has been applied here, and thus I'm thinking you might not be linking to the bootstrap CSS properly. This is reinforced by your mention that nothing is working following the addition of the imported code. Sometimes links have to be direct, like 'https://www.mywebpage.com/css/bootstrap.css', and sometimes you can use other methods for fetching them such as ../../css/bootstrap.css, which is a method utilized to back you up two folders in the structure to where the CSS folder, in theory, might be located.

If you're in a specified folder, and you need to navigate from your location to a CSS page, do your best find out the path of least resistance from where you are. So if I'm working in a file in a folder, and the css and bootstrap is located up two folders, and in another folder titled 'backend' in that hierarchy, here's how I would structure the import function in css:

`@import "../../backend/css/bootstrap.css";`

Where the `../../` tells the page to move up two folders, the `backend` tells the page to open the backend folder, and then `css/bootstrap.css` tells the page to move into the css folder to find the bootstrap document.

Another thing worth noting is that you can work independently in CSS files and link them all in the `<head>` tag in HTML. If linking something through CSS doesn't work, I attempt to link it in HTML first to see if there are larger problems at hand.

Next, I'll move onto the HTML snippet you posted here. I looked it over and noticed there isn't a ton of room for the page to respond in a way you might intend as you don't have the content of the spans, button and divs populated much at all. Sometimes functionality appears after a minimum amount of content or you have to specify that in the CSS. It otherwise looks good, but it's very class heavy. And if any of them are misspelled in either the HTML or CSS, there's a chance that the page will not load as you want it to. I know these things seem trivial, but I do hope they at least give you somewhere to start! :)